# SQL Server insert missing record with select distinct or left join

Tags: sql-server, insert-update

I have a table where is some case we are missing the location record for `location = 'WHS1'`. You will notice the bottom 2 `"TCODE's"` do not have a `location = WHS1` record
I was thinking of doing a select distinct on `TCODE`    `InvYear` and to get  unique records then checking to see if the Location 'WHS1' NOT Exist.

I'm very green at this that you for any help

```
TCODE   InvYear Location    StartingInv Adjustments Damages EndingInv
NY530-1 2015    BRX         625         NULL        NULL    709
NY530-1 2015    LAN         365         NULL        NULL    365
NY530-1 2015    WHS1        432         NULL        NULL    442
NY530-2 2015    BRX         309         NULL        NULL    413
NY530-2 2015    LAN         94          NULL        NULL    96
NY530-2 2015    WHS1        1310        NULL        NULL    1344
NY547-1 2015    BRX         0           NULL        NULL    0
NY547-2 2015    BRX         0           NULL        NULL    0
```

Comment: Could you tell us what exactly u need? Like giving an example of the desired result. So that we can give u the required sql query.

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO TableA (TCODE , InvYear, Location ,StartingInv ,EndingInv)
SELECT DISTINCT TCODE , InvYear, 'WHS1', 0 , 0 
FROM TableA A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM TableA 
                  WHERE A.TCode = TCode
                   AND  A.InvYear = InvYear
                   AND  Location = 'WHS1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how we solved it.
/****** BY Vincent ******/
INSERT INTO [FlynnEMB].[dbo].[TransferInv] (TCODE, InvYear, Location, StartingInv,   EndingInv)
SELECT t.*, 'WHS1' as Location , 0 as StartingInv, 0 as EndingInv
FROM (

SELECT distinct [TCODE]
      ,[InvYear]

FROM [FlynnEMB].[dbo].[TransferInv]

except ( select distinct [TCODE],[InvYear] 
  FROM [FlynnEMB].[dbo].[TransferInv] where Location = 'WHS1'))t